# In the Google Drive API, how can I distinguish between a nonexistent file and a file a user does not have access to?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I am integrating with the Google Drive v3 files API via the Javascript interface.  (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/)

If I try to call `get` on a file that does not exist, it returns a 404.  That is great.

However, if I try to call `get` on a file that the requesting user does not have access to, I also get a 404.  This is not so great.

The documentation seems to say we just have to use a 404 to handle both not found and not authorized (see the note about 404 handling):
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors

If the user goes directly to the file in question via HTTP, the latter would give a 403.

(I would link to concrete examples of documents that return 404 vs. 403, but I don't have enough reputation points yet.)

It's pretty clear that the lack of transparency is only happening in the API.

The API response includes a redirect URL which are links similar to those included above, but I would prefer to keep the users on my site and not lead them to a potential dead end at Google.

Any suggestions for tricks to be able to distinguish these from the JS client side?

Comment: Don't go mixing the HTTP errors my friend. [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) will always be the standard for errors when a file doesnt exist not when a user doesnt have permission to access the file. [403](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#403_the_user_does_not_have_sufficient_permissions_for_file_fileid) in Drive API might mean you dont have permission. If you can't show a concrete example, your case is not justified.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation, it's not doable.  One potential trick, if you somehow have access to an administrator account that would have unfettered access to all files, is to test accessing the file with that account via the API.  If that results in a 200, you can know that the file does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I haven't tested it). I'm assuming you have an ID that you are trying a GET for.

1. Do your files.get. If it fails 404...
2. Try to do a harmless update on that ID, eg. add a custom property

My guess is the update call will fail 403 if it exists and 404 if it doesn't.